# GPS persistence on mobile web app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, gps

As part of my newest project, I have a feature that uses geolocation to track the player's movement in the real world and reward this activity.

It's going well so far but it suffers from needing to have the screen always on. As soon as you turn the screen off the GPS stops updating (or, more accurately, the JavaScript stops running) and when you turn it back on it will just jump you to your new location. This is fine if you were walking a straight line, but any zigzags are lost causing you to almost always lose credit unless you keep that screen on.

This awkwardness continues even when you you just hold the phone loosely by your side: after a while the screen turns off anyway unless you tap it every few minutes. This prevents you just putting it in your pocket, as more than likely you'll butt-press the Home button or something on screen.

I realise the answer is probably "no" for a lot of obvious reasons, but is there any way to have the JavaScript and GPS continue to run even when the phone is asleep?

Worst case (which is what I'm currently doing) I can explain to users that it only works when the screen is on, but you can "check in" every so often for partial credit. But I'd like to be sure there's no other way in a web app. After all, geolocation requires user approval in the first place, maybe there's something for persistence?

Comment: have a look at cordova...

Comment: @Jonasw Interesting, if I understand correctly it's basically a way to build platform native apps (which would have permission to run in the background or when the screen is off) using familiar web technology? Might be a little overkill but definitely interesting if so

Comment: exactly. theres no engine i know that allows the js to run in background, so this may be the only solution ( except learning java)

Comment: @Jonasw Cool. Is [this](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) the plugin I'd need to use when in "tracking mode"?

Comment: @Jonasw Thanks for the pointer, I've played around with it a bit. Unfortunately during early testing, the GPS became extremely inaccurate when the phone was "asleep". My morning walk generated a good hundred points with the screen on, but repeating the walk (with long detour!) with the screen off resulted in only a dozen points and they were quite scattered from my actual path. Seems I may just have to inform users that tracking is only active when the screen is on.

Comment: Another possibility would be to just show a black color fullscreen, so that modern displays can switch off. The device wouldnt go to standby so the gps keeps running....